# How to get min and max value of primitives?

Tags: rust, primitive

How can I store the minimum value of `i32` in a variable?

```java
// Java Example :
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

```cpp
// C++ example
int min = INT_MIN;
```

I want to do something like:

```rust
let min: i32 = i32_MIN_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some `const` defined:

- [`MIN`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#associatedconstant.MIN)
- [`MAX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#associatedconstant.MAX)

```rust
let min: u32 = u32::MIN;
```

They are also defined for other primitive numeric types.